# Installing and Using gnug

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

I am trying to install gnupg not really knowing what I am doing...

What I did: CPanel -> Software -> PHP Selector | extensions

Within this screen, there was an option "gnupg" which was unchecked - so I checked it and then clicked save.

I assumed that gnupg already exists on the server and I have just activated it for the account.  Do I still need to "install" it?

When I try to initiate, I get nothing (see below).  I've googled and checked docs etc but can't see what I am missing - I assume I don't need to 'include' anything because it is in the PATH?

TEST:

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
$publicKey = $gpg->import('test');
var_dump($gpg);
var_dump($publicKey);
```

RESULT:

```
object(gnupg)#229 (0) { } 
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Really good question php-b-grader.

What you have done is all you need to do - NOTE: the object is empty but it is still an object, meaning you instantiated the object - so gnupg is installed